# Android Google Maps API v2 calling getProjection from onResume

Tags: android, onresume, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to get the map bound when my app starts, but

```
    GoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

returns the bounds 0,0,0,0. Is there some kind of listener I could use to see when the

```
    Projection
```

is loaded?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try temporarily registering an `OnCameraChangeListener` and see if it is invoked when the map first loads.

Comment: It also helped me out, thx! I posted a short answer with some code to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574839/google-maps-android-api-v2-getvisibleregion-returns-0/14685255#14685255

Comment: @CommonsWare you could post you answer as a "answer", so I could mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register (temporarily, if needed) an `OnCameraChangeListener`. It will get called whenever the camera changes, which will include the first change when the default map is displayed.