# When can I use GoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, fragment-lifecycle

I have to get **`GoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds`**

But when app is started, its values are all zero.

I tried to get this at onViewCreated, `onActivityCreated` and onStart of `SupportMapFragment`, but it doesn't work. When I can do it? Is there any callback function that notifies when it is ready?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574839/google-maps-android-api-v2-getvisibleregion-returns-0)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `OnCameraChangeListener` to your map.